# Setting highcharts datalabels backgroundColor with the same color of its piechart series

Tags: knockout.js, highcharts

I'm trying to set the backgroundColor of datalabels with the same color of its series (UI reasons).

I've tried to use the formatter option and return a "div" with the desired styles but only the font color applies to the dataLabel.

```
$(function() {
    // Create the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
  plotOptions : {
        series : {

        }
    },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: [["Firefox",6],["MSIE",4],["Chrome",7]],
            size: '60%',
            innerSize: '20%',
  dataLabels : {
                connectorwidth:0,
                enabled : true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter : function() {
                    return $('<div/>').css({
                        'color' : this.series.color, //  don't work
                        'border' : '2px solid ', // work
                        'backgroundColor' : this.series.color // don't work
                    }).text(this.y)[0].outerHTML;
                }
            }

        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.point.color` in you `formatter`:

```
formatter : function() {
    return $('<div/>').css({
        'color' : this.point.color, // work
        'border' : '2px solid ',    // work
        'backgroundColor' : '#fff'  // just white in my case
    }).text(this.y)[0].outerHTML;
}
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2urnx81/1/

Comment: thnks...It work great...can i get the series name(chrome,firefox,..)  nearer to that box area..can u suggest any idea...

Comment: I tried like this but is it possible i can get the this.point.name outside the box  area ..          
 formatter : function() {
                    console.log(this);
                    return $('<div/>').css({
                        'color' : '#bbb', 
                        'backgroundColor' :this.point.color  
                    }).text(this.y + this.point.name)[0].outerHTML;
                }